# Getting the generated sourcecode of a page in notepad

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, text

Is there any way of getting the source code of an HTML browser-page that is showing when i click inspect element(in chrome of firefox) and put it in a notepad(automatically) or maybe accessing it automatically somehow.

I do not want the original sourcecode but the one that is generated after all the javascripts have already run.

I would like to use the code afterwards in another web page and parse it...

later edit: i can actually click the html in the inspect element and click copy html but i need for a nother site to automatically acces this information because i will try reloading the site at regular intervals and need to constantly get the new html

Comment: Right click the `html` element and select 'copy as html', this isn't 'automatic' copying to Notepad; but it's as close as I think you can get. Just open Notepad and hit 'paste.' You might need to format, a little, but it's not so bad.

Comment: if i am not wrong you actually want the html of output generated after all the javascript code is executed. The source code remains the same even after all the javascript code is executed.

Comment: i can actually click the html in the inspect element and click copy html but i need for a nother site to automatically acces this information because i will try reloading the site at regular intervals and need to constantly get the new html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Firebug's HTML tab, you can right click on the  element, and click "Copy HTML".

See also this post: 
[how to get fully computed HTML (instead of source HTML)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364138/how-to-get-fully-computed-html-instead-of-source-html)

Comment: i need it to be done automatically in order to automatically feed it to another program that i use

Answer (score 1):

press `ctrl+u` then it will display `source code of html page` then go to `file menu and save it as html file` in your system. then you can open it in html or another editor like `netbeans /dreamviewer/notepad`. I suggest you to open it in netbeans or dreamviewer will be better then open it in notped.

thanks.

Comment: yes Notepad++ also can  used it depend on which editor is available :-)

Comment: Is `ctrl+u` and all browser function?

Comment: yes ctrl+u working on most of browser like mozilla,chrome,IE..which are normally we use.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm for him.

Comment: I think most of browsers but if in some browser ctrl+u not work then  we can click right mouse button and click on view page source and save that code too... :-)

Comment: i need it to be done automatically in order to automatically feed it to another program that i use

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [web developer plugin](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) for Firefox or Chrome. It gives you the generated source of a page.

Comment: i need it to be done automatically in order to automatically feed it to another program that i use

Answer (score 0):

In Opera , Right Click -> click on Inspect Element -> right click on `<html>` tag -> click on Edit Markup, from there you can copy the entire HTML code.

Edit -> In Oprea, right click on the page `->` click on Source `->` a new tab opens , in the menu bar of newly opened tab you have option `'Save'` , from that option you can save the html code as `.html , .txt.`
Hope this helps you.

Comment: i need it to be done automatically in order to automatically feed it to another program that i use