# how to (programmatically) get fully computed HTML (instead of source HTML)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to learn jQuery and trying to build a Chrome Extension. Hacking around I ended up trying to parse a webpage that loads of javascript and Ajax queries to generate its HTML, how can I programmatically get the final computed HTML being parsed by the browser instead of the source HTML?

My question is inspired by this other question:
[how to get fully computed HTML (instead of source HTML)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364138/how-to-get-fully-computed-html-instead-of-source-html)

The difference is that I really want to understand if this is possible and how to do that programmatically, ideally with JavaScript.

I already tried using:
`$(document).ajaxComplete()`

But with no positive result.

**Updated based on the comments:**

I have no access to the code, I can only send a get request to the website. The website will then return me the page source which itself contains ajax or javascript. I want the Ajax and JavaScript to be rendered so that I can parse whatever it comes out of it.

Comment: You could just use a RegEx to remove all the HTML Entities, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: No, I want to be able to reach the pure html (this means rendering all the non HTML components) so that I can parse it with jQuery.

Comment: Not making sense. It can already be parsed with jQuery.

Comment: Isn't the `.html()` method of jQuery what you want?

Comment: $('html').html(); will get you the current calculated html code.

Comment: None of what suggested in the above comments has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the markup of your document **after scripts execution**, you'll have to append this markup in an iframe or alike.
Then, you'll be able to get the root node via `yourFrame.contentDocument.documentElement`*.

The easiest way for you is to make your AJAX call directly return a Blob, which is what I assume in following code-block, but you could also create it from a text response, or even set the iframe's src to `'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(textResponse)`.

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
// since we need to append the iframe for it to load, lets hide it
iframe.width = iframe.height = 0;
iframe.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute; opacity:0;')

$('body').append(iframe); // this is a jQuery question...

iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(AJAXresponseAsBlob);
// here we will trigger the catching at page load
iframe.onload = function() {
  var outer = iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
  iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe); // we don't need it anymore
  doSomethingWith(outer);
}
```

[**Live Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/19cu3r04/) (since stack-snippets are sand-boxed...)

*IIRC, there were some implementation quirks as to how access the iframe content, but I'll let you search for it, this has already been answered many times in the past.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer and explanation. I get an error running your code in my extension: `Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: ReferenceError: AJAXresponseAsBlob is not defined`

Comment: @Jack, did you defined this variable ? Either you are able to make an XHR with the `'blob'` `responseType`, in which case it would just be `var AJAXresponseAsBlob = XHR.response`, either you receive the response as text, in which case it should be `var AJAXresponseAsBlob = new Blob([XHR.response], {type:'text/html'}); '

Comment: I understood, thanks. Now I have the following issue, `document.body.childNodes` returns an array of nodes, but `Array.prototype.filter.call(document.body.childNodes, function(n){return n.nodeType===8;})` returns an empty array. Why? Also I don't really understand what `n.nodeType===8` does

Comment: @Jack, this was just for the snippet, since I couldn't make a real xhr request from jsfiddle, I wrote the markup in a comment. So this part is just getting the comment in the fiddle. But you should not use it in your own script, use only the code in the answer, where AJAXrequest is the response from your request.

Comment: Done as you suggested, made my `AJAXresponseAsBlob = $(document)`  but now get: `Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.`

Comment: @Jack, ... I never told to set `AJAXresponseAsBlob` to `$(document)`... Please provide a jsfiddle with your actual code... I can't learn you basics of javascript in comments.