# how to get all resources after rendering html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-crawler

at [how to get fully computed HTML (instead of source HTML)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364138/how-to-get-fully-computed-html-instead-of-source-html) is the idea to save the rendered page. But HTML is not complete, I am missing pictures/js.

For example chrome saves it in this format:

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png"
      sizes="16x16"
      href="//media-static.examples.org/app_themes/image/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
```

Are there any possibilities to save the resources(e.g. chrome, firefox,.. )?
Is there a better crawler for this purpose?

Comment: You cant ensure that you got "all resources" due to lazy-loading and asynchronous tasks that could happen after a while. Could you specify a use case? To maybe find a solution for your specific one.

Comment: My Chrome has a "Format" option in the "Save Page As..." dialog that includes "Webpage, Complete" and saves a folder with a bunch of images, JavaScript and CSS files, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz that still won't load the mentioned resources, that's why I was asking for a use-case.

Comment: `wget --mirror` with the `--convert-links` and `--page-requisites` flags may point you in the right direction, I suppose.